# Returning java numeric arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I have a method that requires a `double[]` as a return type.

Why is it that this:

```
double[] zero = {0, 0};
return zero;
```

will compile successfully, but this:

```
return {0, 0};
```

will not? Is there any way that I can directly return an array?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that `{0,0}` is something the compiler can not understand because among others that is nor a primitive neither a defined object...
The solution for that is that you  return an array anonymously like doing

```
private double[] fooMethod(...) {
     // your logic here....
     return new double[] {0.0, 0.0};
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can return an anonymous array:

```
return new double[]{0,0};
```